# jenkins tomcat deploy with curl won't update war file

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, curl

I have a jenkins pipeline to build and deploy war file to my tomcat server

there is my deploy step

```
    stage('tomcat deploy') {
    sh "curl -v -u admin:admin -T target/test.war http://host:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/test&update=true "}
```

it works if I don't have a war file already deployed on the server, but if it there it won't update\replace it

in the logs it looks like this

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ update=true
+ curl -v -u admin:admin -T target/test.war 'http://host:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/test'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0[Pipeline] }
```

how to make it to update my war file if it's already on the server ?

Answer (score 1):

The `&` in the URL is being interpreted by the shell rather than being included in the URL. Escaping it as `\&` should fix it.